# Counting categories in a specific month

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am working on an active google spreadsheet and i am in need to to count specific categories for cases in each month

Right now i have the follow sheet setup
B(issue date),C(unit),F(category)
and
B(check in),C(unit),I(category),L(check out)
These are in different tabs but for stats and records i need to keep count of cases and categories in specific months.

I have tried using :
=query('sheet'!$B:$F, "select C,D,F where C>='9/1/2021' and C<='9/30/2021 group by C' ", 1)

But it just gives me the header and it mentions that the result is empty

Is there any way to keep an automatic count of cases in specific months or do i need to make new tabs for each month?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Test file here :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UgUGtCAw3ze1VRFX5bYW5Dh0WMcNn3JCfWscKZDbFHQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

I am doing it on my phone so it's hard to properly set it up

Comment: It would help if you can share a sample sheet with sample data to work that are similar to your actual sheet to replicate your setup.

Comment: Added the test sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(sheet!B:F, 
 "select C,D,F 
  where month(C)+1 = 9", 1)
```

[image]

#### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaGstnA6OZBr-Z0aA4iFocpTog1xF23cTjjq_EViC58/edit#gid=585841464)

Comment: I tried and it gives me an error. It's expecting a *(* but there ain't one missing.

Comment: @Danion answer updated

Comment: I am so pissed at myself for not figuring it out sooner. It was so simple. I had 5 different tabs on my actual sheet. Trying to get the formulas to work. Thank you very much.